# Is it possible to display irregular values in the scale bar in QGIS 2.8?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, scale, scale-bar

Is it possible to display irregular - increasing values in scale bar in print composer?
For example: 5, 20, 100, 250.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, no. You can only define the number of segments for the left and right part, separately (see the properties of scalebar in the composer editor).